# CSS doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I want to create a website.

**Prerequisites**

CSS doesn't work.

**Expected value**

I want to set the size oflogo.svg to width: 120px;,height: 40px;.

**Reproduction procedure**

Run the code below.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ポートフォリオサイト1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/css/header.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <a href="index.html" class="header__profile-button"><img src="image/logo.svg" alt="プロフィール"></a>
        <nav class="header__breadcrumb-trail">
                <a href="" class="header__breadcrumb-trail">About</a>
                <a href="" class="header__breadcrumb-trail">Bicycle</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main class="main">
        <div class="main__mainvisual">
            <img class="main__mainvisual-image" src="image/mainvisual (1).jpg" alt="メインビジュアル">
        </div>

        <div class="main__about">
            <p class="main__about-title">About</p>
            <img class="main__profile-icon-image"src="image/about.jpg" alt="プロフィールアイコン">
            <p class="main__name-text">Yusuke Oyama</p>
            <p class="main__introduction-text">
                初めまして。atago_ITと申します。
                とある開発コミュニティで、QAエンジニアをやっています。
                自転車と万年筆が大好きです。よろしくお願いいたします。
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="bicycle">
           <div class="bicycle__bicycle-image">
                <img src="image/bicycle1.jpg" alt="">
           </div> 
           <div class="bicycle__bicycle-image">
                <img src="image/bicycle2.jpg" alt="">
           </div>
           <div class="bicycle__bicycle-image">
                <img src="image/bicycle3.jpg" alt="">
           </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer class="footer">
        <p class="footer__text">
            ©2021 atago_IT
        </p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

header.css

```
.header .header__profile_button {
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Is this just a simple typo? `.header__profile_button` vs. `.header__profile-button`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because if the Prerequisites is that CSS does not work, there is no reason to ask why CSS does not work and the question is not why CSS does work.

Answer (score 2):

No worries it is just a minor typo mistake. (.header__profile_button vs. .header__profile-button)

Are you using Visual Studio Code? Once you select a text, this editor will show all instances.

[image]